# catch error occurring in pipeline and adapter level in ESB exception management portal

Tags: biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.0

I need to catch error occurring in  pipeline and adapter level in ESB exception management portal...

We are not using any orchestrations..also we are using xml pipeline

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Put a tick in **Enable routing for failed messages**, found on the General tab for Receive Ports and on the Transport Advanced Options for Send Ports.  Rather than suspending the message will be routed to the ESB exception portal.

Option 2: If you want the message to suspend so you can retry it, add a new filter to the ALL.Exception Send Port `BTS.AckType == NACK'
That rule will then cause notifications for ALL port failures.

[image: Global NACK rule]

If you have a mixture of ports with routing for failed messages and the global NACK rule, then for those ports you will get two failure messages unless you make your NACK rule more specific e.g. `BTS.AckType == NACK and BTS.ReceivePortName == nameofreceiveport` or  `BTS.AckType == NACK and BTS.SPName == nameofsendport`

[image]